Run shell script when bluetooth device connects/disconnects
I have a bluetooth headset and when I connect/disconnect it to/from my Mac, I want to run a command that requires super user permissions. I've read of ways to do it using udev on Linux, but as far as I know, udev is specific to Linux. Another answer on SO here said to use launchd and watch the path /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist, but this path never changes on my mac, as noted in some of the comments to the answer.
I suppose scheduling a custom launch daemon to run every 5 seconds or so might work, but this seems clunky and a waste of resources even if I define a relatively light process.
Related Links:

how-do-i-run-a-script-when-a-bluetooth-device-connects (AskUbuntu) Doesn't work because it's Linux
run-a-script-when-bluetooth-device-is-connected (Unix & Linux) Another udev example for Linux Mint

Are there macOS specific hooks or solutions to this automation task?

Shortcuts for iOS has a similar trigger, have you looked in that app on macOS? Also investigate BTT and this thread.

@bmike, thanks for the ideas! Good though with the iOS Shortcuts... unfortunately, Apple hasn't built Automations into their shortcuts app. You can get additional add on apps like Shortery (https://apps.apple.com/us/app/shortery/id1594183810) but as far as I can see, you can't trigger based on bluetooth connections. Unfortunately, BTT is a paid software (though it has a 45 day free trial) but otherwise it looks like it could do the trick.
--EDIT-- I went back and re-read the description on Shortery, and it appears that it does run on bluetooth connect/disconnect! I will give it a try.........

Unfortunately again, Shortery only runs bluetooth triggers with a pro version - $12.99 per year.

Sounds like you’ve got two excellent options if you ever want to invest in a tool that saves you effort or time re-implementing their products.
